# How to display on TKinter what a function returns?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to display in the window what a function returns in Tkinter text. But I can't do it.
Can you help me please

Here is my code (there are no errors, but nothing is displayed):

```
from tkinter import *


fen = Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')

a=10

def calcul(a):
    b=a*10
    return b

def DoCalcul():
    calcul(a)

text1=Label(fen, Text=DoCalcul(), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))
text1.pack()



fen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its probably better to use either a StringVar() or update the label directly then to use a function call in the text field. By putting a function call in the text field it runs instantly on start up and will not be updated down the road and this can cause other problems. You can also run the calculation the the text field if you are wanting to simply apply a calculated value permanently to a label.

Comment: Also your typo of `Text` needs to be `text`. Because this argument is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning a value from  the `DoCalcul` function. Also you had used `Text` rather than `text` as a parameter keyword for `Label`

See below code

```
from tkinter import *


fen = Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')

a=10

def calcul(a):
    b=a*10
    return b

def DoCalcul():
    return calcul(a)

text1=Label(fen, text=f"Result is {DoCalcul()}", width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13)) 
text1.pack()



fen.mainloop()



fen.mainloop()
```

I've also updated the code to show how to add additional text using python f-strings.

Comment: Tkinter `text` fields can take a number just fine it is not "expecting" a string for the text field in the Label.

Comment: Thanks !! Last question, is it possible to make a constructed sentence of this kind:

Comment: ````
text1=Label(fen, text="The result is:" DoCalcul(), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))

Comment: `text1=Label(fen, text="The result is:" DoCalcul(), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))`

Comment: @TimPython Updated the answer in line with your question and comments of others.

Comment: @TimPython yes you can concatenate in the field just fine. You need to use `+` or '.format()` or make use of `f` strings.

Comment: @scotty3785 please also note that you corrected a typo in the label that would otherwise throw an error when assigning a value to it. It might also be worth noting that f strings were introduced in python 3.6 so anyone working with previous versions cannot use f string here.

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution is to add a return to your function:

```
def DoCalcul():
    return calcul(a)
```

Another issue is that you should explicitly call the global variable `a`. Python does eventually check global if it cannot find the variable in the local namespace but this may cause issues down the road as your code expands so instead add the global reference.

```
def DoCalcul():
    global a
    return calcul(a)
```

That said Its not common to use a function call in a text field so lets look at some other options.

1. Instead of importing * you can do `import tkinter as tk`. This servers 2 purposes. One is so we do not override any existing imported methods/functions/classes ect and to make it easier to ID where we are using tkinter related methods.
2. For small calculations like this you can write it into the text field directly or you can use a StringVar()/IntVar() to hold a dynamically changing value if you need to keep your label updating.
3. You have a typo in your label. it is `text` and not `Text`.

You use 2 functions to do what one function can do just fine if you insist on using a function call in your label directly:

```
import tkinter as tk


fen = tk.Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')
a = 10


def calcul(a):
    b=a*10
    return b


text1 = tk.Label(fen, text=calcul(a), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))
text1.pack()
```

To run the calculation in the label directly you can do this:

```
import tkinter as tk


fen = tk.Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')
a = 10

text1 = tk.Label(fen, text=a*10, width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))
text1.pack()

fen.mainloop()
```

Using a `StringVar()` or `IntVar()` here you can do this:

```
import tkinter as tk


fen = tk.Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')
a = 10

label_var = tk.StringVar(fen)
label_var.set(a*10)

text1 = tk.Label(fen, text=label_var.get(), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13))
text1.pack()

fen.mainloop()
```

Edit:

To answer your question about concatenation in the comments you can try one of the following 3 methods if to do that.

`.format()` the use of `+` or `f` strings:

```
import tkinter as tk


fen = tk.Tk()
fen.geometry('500x500')
a = 10

label_var = tk.StringVar(fen)
label_var.set(a*10)

tk.Label(fen, text="The result is: " + label_var.get(), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13)).pack()
tk.Label(fen, text="The result is: {}".format(label_var.get()), width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13)).pack()
tk.Label(fen, text=f"The result is: {label_var.get()}", width=80, height=2, fg="green", font=('arial', 13)).pack()


fen.mainloop()
```